# Independent clauses in conditional sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

The decision to carry out a mission shall be disclosed after the decision has been taken, and the mission is complete.

In the above sentence, the two independent clauses after the word "after", sepearated by comma and the conjunction "and", are the two conditions for disclosure. I want to know whether the disclosure shall be made only once (ie., after both conditions are met) or twice (ie., after each condition is met).

Comment: Did you write this sentence or did you find it somewhere? If you found it, please include a link to its source.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using *and*, it means the disclosure will be made once, after both things have been done. You could list 15 things and combine them with *and*, and the disclosure would be made once, after all 15 things had been done.

By the way, the use of a comma before *and the mission complete* is unnecessary  and worsens the quality of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

An informal rule of commas is to use them before conjunctions ("and", "but", "or", etc.) when the action does not naturally flow from the first part to the next part.  Otherwise commas break the flow and suggest the two parts are separate events.

For example:

> I started my car and drove away.
>
> I started my car, and the engine caught on fire.

The listener naturally expects someone to drive off after they start their car, so no comma is needed.  Because the second sentence has an unexpected result, it's common to use a comma to emphasize the change in direction.  "I started my car and the engine caught on fire" is not *wrong*, but without the comma there's the implication that a fire is normal and routine every time I start my car.

In your example, the comma before "and the mission is complete" breaks the flow and makes the sentence more difficult to understand.  The two requirements in the second half of the sentence go together and should not be separated. Also you can throw an "only" in there to emphasize the temporal relationship, "[A] should happen *only* after [B] and [C]."

Comment: The sentence is from a statute. A decision can be disclosed only after it is taken and, therefore, the first condition ("the decision has been taken") looks superfluous unless the intent is to mandate two disclosures. That is the confusion here. @Alan

Comment: I don't see how you can disclose something twice.  Once it's disclosed, it's disclosed.  Also if you mean to do something twice, it's nice to the reader to be clear about it by using "again" -- "A will happen only after B, and again after C".  Good writing should be clear no matter what sentence structure you use.